# Is compiling with -s the same as making everything static?

Tags: c, static

Declaring a function as `static` makes it only availiable in its file, and compiling a program with `-s` makes all the global functions and variables in it unnaccessible from outside the app. So if I just compile an app with `-s`, does it have the same effect as making everything static or is it more complicated than that?

To put it in other words, would these two produce the same executable:

```
/*** cc -s main.c ***/

#include <stdio.h>

void a(){
    printf("Hello world!\n");
}

int main(void){
    a();
    return 0;
}

###############################

/*** cc main.c ***/

#include <stdio.h>

static void a(){
    printf("Hello world!\n");
}

int main(void){
    a();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You appear to be asking about the behavior of a specific compiler, but you are not specifying which compiler you are asking about. Please [edit] the question to clarify this.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I think -s has the same behavior on all compilers. It's the same as running the `strip` command on an app after compiling it.

Comment: Some compiler use compatible options for some things, but not everything, and not every compiler. For your specific compiler, you should read its documentation what `-s` might do.

Comment: And stripping symbol and debugging information when *linking* (not compiling) is not the same thing as making functions `static`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks, that's what I was wondering about. What's the difference between the two though? (other than how static limits the function to its file)

Comment: Stripping the executable makes the file smaller and makes it harder to debug. That has nothing to do with declaring things `static`. `static` functions and variables cannot be linked to externally by other object files or libraries that make up the program.

Comment: I recommend [this reference about storage duration and linkage](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The -s option when compiling does not affect the accessibility of functions and variables from outside the application.
-s only strips symbols, so the executable will be a bit smaller.